# wireshark showing error dialogue on start

Tags: lua, ubuntu-16.04, wireshark

I have build wireshark-2.4.2 on ubuntu 16.04 machine. Build and install was successful without any warning or Error. But after starting wireshark I'm getting following error.

- With root privileged,

  `$ sudo wireshark`

  I'm getting following error message on wireshark window.

  `Lua: Error during loading:
  [string "/usr/local/share/wireshark/init.lua"]:44: dofile has been disabled due to running Wireshark as superuser. See https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges for help in running Wireshark as an unprivileged user.`
- as normal user

  `$ wireshark`

  Than I'm getting following error

  `You don't have permission to read the file "init.lua".`

  `Error loading table 'SMI Paths': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'SMI Modules': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'GeoIP Database Paths': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'OID Tables': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Custom BootP/DHCP Options (Excl. suboptions)': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Force Decode by Channel': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Decryption Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Node bodytypes': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'DMP Security Classifications': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'DPS Security Mode Templates': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'DPS Session Keys': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'DPS Identity Secrets': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'DTLS RSA Keylist': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Device-Specific Profiles': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'NodeID-Specific Profiles': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'ESS Category Attributes': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Endpoint and Channel Configuration': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Custom HTTP Header Fields': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'WEP and WPA Decryption Keys': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Static Addresses': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Keys': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Custom IMF headers': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'ESP SAs': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'IKEv1 Decryption Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'IKEv2 Decryption Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'K12 Protocols': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'LBMPDM-TCP tag definitions': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'LBMR tag definitions': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'LBT-RM tag definitions': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'LBT-RU tag definitions': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'LBT-TCP tag definitions': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Custom LDAP AttributeValue types': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Static LCID -> drb Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'PDCP UE security keys': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'PRES Users Context List': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Kind-ID Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'SCCP Users Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Chunk types for the statistics dialog': Permission` denied`

  `Error loading table 'Custom SIP Header Fields': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'SIP authorization users': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'SNMP Users': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'SNMP Enterprise Specific Trap Types': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'SSL Decrypt': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'NM User Data Fields Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'User DLTs Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Bitstream Channel Table': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Pre-configured Keys': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'ZigBee GP Security Keys': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Display Filter Macros': Permission denied`

  `Error loading table 'Expert Info Severity Level Configuration': Permission denied`

  `Can't open global preferences file "/usr/local/share/wireshark/preferences": Permission denied.`

  `Could not open global disabled protocols file
  "/usr/local/share/wireshark/disabled_protos": Permission denied.`

  `Could not open global enabled protocols file
  "/usr/local/share/wireshark/enabled_protos": Permission denied.`

  `Could not open global heuristic dissectors file
  "/usr/local/share/wireshark/heuristic_protos": Permission denied.`

  `Could not open your capture filter file
  "/usr/local/share/wireshark/cfilters": Permission denied.`

  `Could not open global filter file
  "/usr/local/share/wireshark/colorfilters": Permission denied.`

I have tried with following post but not succeed
[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/454734/running-wireshark-lua-error-during-loading
[2] https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/7976/wireshark-setup-linux-for-nonroot-user
[3] https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges
[4] https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2048826.html
[5] https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/42982/wireshark-1996-for-mac-osx-10103-can-t-open-preferences-file

Does any one have idea What's going on wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by changing parmission of wireshark files located at /usr/local/share/wireshark.

Log in as a root,

`$ chmod -R 777 /usr/local/share/wireshark`

Now from non-root user I'm able to run wireshark without any error popup. :)